# how to impliment Haystacksearch fetched autocomplete

Tags: django, elasticsearch, autocomplete, django-haystack, elasticsearch-5

I want implement fetching in autocomplete, here is my autocomplete function

```
def autocomplete(request):
fetch_field = request.GET.get('fetch_field')
sqs = SearchQuerySet().autocomplete(
    content_auto=request.GET.get(
        'query',
        ''))[
    :5]
s = []
for result in sqs:
    d = {"value": result.title, "data": result.object.slug}
    s.append(d)
output = {'suggestions': s}
print('hihi' ,output)
return JsonResponse(output)
```

Now I can get fetch fields but I don't know how to fetch with SearchQuerySet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(field_want_to_fetch = fetch_field ).autocomplete(
content_auto=request.GET.get(
    'query',
    ''))[
:5]
```

Use this !!